# Animate scroll to anchor on page

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollto

I've tried a bunch of solutions from the other users on stackoverflow but I just wasn't able to get anything to work. Can anyone show me how to animate the scroll to the anchors on [this page](http://www.shonnyboymushi.com/my-work1.html). Any help would be greaty appreciated!

(Sorry, I'm new to writing code for websites and yes I am using weebly and it can be terrible but it'll have to do. I am able to upload javascript files and link to them through CSS and HTML)

Comment: what do you mean animate the scroll to the anchors?

Comment: Like he did on his website but it is not animated right now :)

Answer (score 2):

What about that [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BjpWB/4/)?

It scrolls to a specific ID !

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

$("#link").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor('id3');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function ScrollTo () {
    $('a').click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
    }, 500);
    return false;
});
}
```

and format your links as follows:

```
<a href="#aboutUs" onClick="ScrollTo()">About Us</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a animated/smooth scroll you can use:

```
var anchor = $('a[name=Photoshop]').offset().top
$(document.body).animate({
         scrollTop: var
     }, 2000);
```

If you just want a fast scroll you can use `var anchor = $('a[name=Photoshop]').offset().top`
And then `$(document.body).scrollTop(anchor)`

Answer (score 0):

I have also had trouble with this, the best tutorial that I used was
http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/10/improved-animated-scrolling-script-for-same-page-links
Make sure your anchor links are within a tags

```
<a id="work></a>
```

Then link to them with the hash tag

```
<a href="#work"></a>
```

Comment: Anchor links **have** to be within a tags, [the a stands for anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) - also, your code just shows how to create an anchor link, it doesn't show how to animate the process, though your link does.

Answer (score 0):

I have a function which works well for me which will automatically animate the scroll an anchor tag is clicked;

```
$("a").click(function(event){
    if(event.target.href.indexOf("#")!=-1){
        var arrhash=event.target.href.split("#");
        $('html, body').animate(
            { scrollTop: $('a[name=' + arrhash[1] + ']').offset().top },
            500,    // this is the animation time
            function (){ return false; }    // what to do after the animation
        );
    }
});
```

Any time you have Jump to somewhere - it will be animated. Also, if javascript isn't working, it will fall back gracefully to the standard jump.

I couldn't get Abhishek Umrao 's code at the top to work so I got this working instead based on their idea.

Answer (score 0):

The other proposed answers allow animate on scroll for a precise link. JJ Shaw's answer does not work and moreover it triggers an event for all links even those who are not towards an anchor. For all those who want like me animate on scroll for all links to an anchor here is a solution that works properly.

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
    var anchor= $(this.getAttribute('href'));
    if( anchor.length ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $('html, body').stop().animate({
          scrollTop: anchor.offset().top
       }, 500);
    }
});
```